# mysql query result to clickable url

Tags: php, html, mysql, dictionary, gps

I have a database that stores user name and gps data, etc..
I want to convert the query results to a clickable url link.
So far I got:

```
$data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM geo_data");
if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['user'];
echo "<br>http://maps.google.com/?q=". $row["latitude"]. ",". $row["longitude"]. " <br><br>";
```

The result :

```
user

http://maps.google.com/?q=47.470931799999995,19.024870399999998 ,
```

But this is not a clickable url (although here it looks).
If I copy it to the address bar of the browser, it will open.
How can I make this clickable?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Clickable links are anchor tags `<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q= ........"....>visible bit</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an anchor [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag :

```
echo '<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q='. $row["latitude"]. ','. $row["longitude"]. '">Click me</a> <br><br>';
```